# Using the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, prove that $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I have difficulty understanding the solution given below. I can't see that $R$ is clearly countable, how can I express this as the countable union of countable sets? How do we ensure this is not a countable product? And I think the formulation here is wrong. Shouldn't we have $a_m$, for $m \ge 1$ instead of $a_k$? Because having $a_k x^k$ we are restricting the rational numbers to the ones $k\le n$. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain these points to me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding countability: well, it's already written down in your question, you just have to recognize it. Look at the map $\phi_n:\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}\rightarrow \cal{R}$ defined by
$$(q_0,\dots, q_n)\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^nq_k x^k $$
and let $\cal{R_n}:= \phi_n(\mathbb{Q}^{n+1})$. $\phi_k$ is clearly one to one and the image is countable, since the domain of definition is, as finite product of countable sets. Now it's not difficult to see that $\cal{R}=\cup_k \cal{R_k}$

I cannot see where you want to replace $a_k$ by $a_m$.

Comment: because if we have $a_k$ then the only constant we get is $a_0$ and nothing else. The only way we get no power of $x$ and only constant is when $n=0$ in which case $k=0$ so we only get $a_0$. This is my understanding. So I was thinking $R=\{\sum_{k=0}^n a_m x^k | a_m\in \mathbb{Q}, m\in \mathbb{N}, 0 \le k \le n, n \ge 0\}$ will do.

Comment: Isn't this $R$ which is equal to the $R$ you've constructed?

Comment: @takecare Regarding the first comment: no, $a_0$ is chosen arbritrarily from $\mathbb{Q}$, so you get all constants in $\mathbb{Q}$. Your understanding of the definition is not correct. I don't understand what the question is in the second comment. If you are asking me whether I'v just used a complicated way to write down $\cal R$, then yes, because I was hoping this shows how countability can be verified.

Comment: For the second one I mean is the $R$ I wrote down wrong? And my understanding is that $\{a_k\}$ is the sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$, and as I said in the first comment, the only way we get just a constant polynomial is when $n=0$, and this forces $k$ to be $0$, so we only get $a_0$. In the given notation, $k$ is fixed here, so I don't see how my understanding of the definition is incorrect.

Comment: @takecare You seem to think that $a_k$ is a fixed sequence, as it seems, a fixed enumeration of the rationals, and this is where your understanding is incorrect. This would, in fact, not work. The $a_k$ in the definition or $\cal{R}$ are just placeholders. For each fixed index $k$ they are taken from all of $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, the admissible values for $a_0$ is all of $\mathbb{Q}$ as well.